# FF 3.5 extension: window.title is 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox3.5

From a sidebar in Firefox 3.5 I am getting a reference to the main window with:

```
var mainWindow = window.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIInterfaceRequestor)
               .getInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIWebNavigation)
               .QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIDocShellTreeItem)
               .rootTreeItem
               .QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIInterfaceRequestor)
               .getInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIDOMWindow);
```

Then, `mainWindow.title` is undefined (this works in Firefox 3.0).

I've also tried:

```
mainWindow.getBrowser().selectedBrowser.contentWindow.title (also undefined)
```

and it might be worth noting that

```
mainWindow.getBrowser().selectedBrowser.contentWindow.location.href
```

returns the correct URL.

Thanks!
Noah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you really want is `mainWindow.content.document.title`.  The title attribute exists on a document, not a window and should work in 3.0 and beyond.

Answer (score 0):

It was removed in [bug 450977](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=450977) after [being deprecated since 2004](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=264102).

If my reading of the bugs is correct, the correct replacement is `document.title`.

Comment: `document.title` works if your script is running in the main window, `browser.xul`. I wouldn't expect it to work from a sidebar but I haven't tried so I don't know.

Comment: Yes, "document.title" would return the sidebar's title instead of the real title, but the OP clearly knows how to get from the sidebar context to the browser.xul window.